# ScheduledTaskAgent Project is not working in device but is working in Emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i have make a one project and add one ScheduledTaskAgent and add This code is OnInvoke function

```
string toastMessage = "Periodic task running.";

            ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
            toast.Title = "Background Agent Sample";
            toast.Content = toastMessage;
            toast.Show();
```

and WAAppManifast.xml Code is

```
<Tasks>
      <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml"/>
    <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
            <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="ScheduledTaskAgent1" Source="ScheduledTaskAgent1" Type="ScheduledTaskAgent1.ScheduledAgent" />
    </ExtendedTask>
    </Tasks>
```

and in MainPage.xaml code is

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartPeriodicAgent();
            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }
         private void StartPeriodicAgent()
        {

    AgentIsEnabled = true;
 
    // If this task already exists, remove it
    PeriodicTask =ScheduledActionService.Find(PeriodicTaskname ) as PeriodicTask;
    if (PeriodicTask != null)
    {
        RemoveAgent( PeriodicTaskname );
    }

    PeriodicTask = new PeriodicTask(PeriodicTaskname);
    PeriodicTask.Description ="This demonstrates a periodic task.";
 
    try
    {
        ScheduledActionService.Add( PeriodicTask );
       // PeriodicStackPanel.DataContext = PeriodicTask;
 
    #if(DEBUG_AGENT)
        ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(
            PeriodicTaskname,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 2 ) );
    #endif
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
    {
        if (exception.Message.Contains(
            "BNS Error: The action is disabled" ))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Background agents for this applicationhave been disabled by the user." );
            AgentIsEnabled = false;
           // PeriodicCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
}
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(
            System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            PeriodicTask =
                ScheduledActionService.Find(PeriodicTaskname)
                as PeriodicTask;


        }
        private void RemoveAgent(string PeriodicTaskname)
        {
            ScheduledActionService.Remove(PeriodicTaskname);
        }





    }
```

i have add a debug in **OnNavigatedTo** function, This function is run properly  then after 2 second error is show The error is 
**Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'ScheduledTaskAgent1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**
I think my application is not be able to call ScheduledTaskAgent OnInvoke function 
Please Help me where i doing a mistake